# Porting (simply-typed) lambda calculus term saturation proof from Coq to Agda

Tags: recursion, coq, agda, termination

I'm trying to port [`msubst_R`](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Norm.html#msubst_R) from [Software Foundations, vol. 2](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Norm.html) to Agda. I'm trying to avoid a lot of busywork by using a typed representation for terms. Below is my port of everything up to `msubst_R`; I think everything is fine below but it's needed for the problematic part.

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality hiding (subst)
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Unit
open import Relation.Binary
open import Data.Star
open import Level renaming (zero to lzero)
open import Data.Product
open import Function.Equivalence hiding (sym)
open import Function.Equality using (_⟨$⟩_)


data Ty : Set where
  fun : Ty → Ty → Ty

infixl 21 _▷_

data Ctx : Set where
  [] : Ctx
  _▷_ : Ctx → Ty → Ctx

data Var (t : Ty) : Ctx → Set where
  vz : ∀ {Γ} → Var t (Γ ▷ t)
  vs : ∀ {Γ u} → Var t Γ → Var t (Γ ▷ u)

data _⊆_ : Ctx → Ctx → Set where
  done : ∀ {Δ} → [] ⊆ Δ
  keep : ∀ {Γ Δ a} → Γ ⊆ Δ → Γ ▷ a ⊆ Δ ▷ a
  drop : ∀ {Γ Δ a} → Γ ⊆ Δ → Γ ⊆ Δ ▷ a

⊆-refl : ∀ {Γ} → Γ ⊆ Γ
⊆-refl {[]} = done
⊆-refl {Γ ▷ _} = keep ⊆-refl

data Tm (Γ : Ctx) : Ty → Set where
  var : ∀ {t} → Var t Γ → Tm Γ t
  lam : ∀ t {u} → (e : Tm (Γ ▷ t) u) → Tm Γ (fun t u)
  app : ∀ {u t} → (f : Tm Γ (fun u t)) → (e : Tm Γ u) → Tm Γ t

wk-var : ∀ {Γ Δ t} → Γ ⊆ Δ → Var t Γ → Var t Δ
wk-var done ()
wk-var (keep Γ⊆Δ) vz = vz
wk-var (keep Γ⊆Δ) (vs v) = vs (wk-var Γ⊆Δ v)
wk-var (drop Γ⊆Δ) v = vs (wk-var Γ⊆Δ v)

wk : ∀ {Γ Δ t} → Γ ⊆ Δ → Tm Γ t → Tm Δ t
wk Γ⊆Δ (var v) = var (wk-var Γ⊆Δ v)
wk Γ⊆Δ (lam t e) = lam t (wk (keep Γ⊆Δ) e)
wk Γ⊆Δ (app f e) = app (wk Γ⊆Δ f) (wk Γ⊆Δ e)

data _⊢⋆_ (Γ : Ctx) : Ctx → Set where
  [] : Γ ⊢⋆ []
  _▷_ : ∀ {Δ t} → Γ ⊢⋆ Δ → Tm Γ t → Γ ⊢⋆ Δ ▷ t

⊢⋆-wk : ∀ {Γ Δ} t → Γ ⊢⋆ Δ → Γ ▷ t ⊢⋆ Δ
⊢⋆-wk t [] = []
⊢⋆-wk t (σ ▷ e) = (⊢⋆-wk t σ) ▷ wk (drop ⊆-refl) e

⊢⋆-mono : ∀ {Γ Δ t} → Γ ⊢⋆ Δ → Γ ▷ t ⊢⋆ Δ ▷ t
⊢⋆-mono σ = ⊢⋆-wk _ σ ▷ var vz

⊢⋆-refl : ∀ {Γ} → Γ ⊢⋆ Γ
⊢⋆-refl {[]} = []
⊢⋆-refl {Γ ▷ _} = ⊢⋆-mono ⊢⋆-refl

subst-var : ∀ {Γ Δ t} → Γ ⊢⋆ Δ → Var t Δ → Tm Γ t
subst-var [] ()
subst-var (σ ▷ x) vz = x
subst-var (σ ▷ x) (vs v) = subst-var σ v

subst : ∀ {Γ Δ t} → Γ ⊢⋆ Δ → Tm Δ t → Tm Γ t
subst σ (var x) = subst-var σ x
subst σ (lam t e) = lam t (subst (⊢⋆-mono σ) e)
subst σ (app f e) = app (subst σ f) (subst σ e)

data Value : {Γ : Ctx} → {t : Ty} → Tm Γ t → Set where
  lam : ∀ {Γ t} → ∀ u (e : Tm _ t) → Value {Γ} (lam u e)

data _==>_ {Γ} : ∀ {t} → Rel (Tm Γ t) lzero where
  app-lam : ∀ {t u} (f : Tm _ t) {v : Tm _ u} → Value v → app (lam u f) v ==> subst (⊢⋆-refl ▷ v) f
  appˡ : ∀ {t u} {f f′ : Tm Γ (fun u t)} → f ==> f′ → (e : Tm Γ u) → app f e ==> app f′ e
  appʳ : ∀ {t u} {f} → Value {Γ} {fun u t} f → ∀ {e e′ : Tm Γ u} → e ==> e′ → app f e ==> app f e′

_==>*_ : ∀ {Γ t} → Rel (Tm Γ t) _
_==>*_ = Star _==>_

NF : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} → Rel A b → A → Set _
NF step x = ∄ (step x)

value⇒normal : ∀ {Γ t e} → Value {Γ} {t} e → NF _==>_ e
value⇒normal (lam t e) (_ , ())

Deterministic : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} → Rel A b → Set _
Deterministic step = ∀ {x y y′} → step x y → step x y′ → y ≡ y′

deterministic : ∀ {Γ t} → Deterministic (_==>_ {Γ} {t})
deterministic (app-lam f _) (app-lam ._ _) = refl
deterministic (app-lam f v) (appˡ () _)
deterministic (app-lam f v) (appʳ f′ e) = ⊥-elim (value⇒normal v (, e))
deterministic (appˡ () e) (app-lam f v)
deterministic (appˡ f e) (appˡ f′ ._) = cong _ (deterministic f f′)
deterministic (appˡ f e) (appʳ f′ _) = ⊥-elim (value⇒normal f′ (, f))
deterministic (appʳ f e) (app-lam f′ v) = ⊥-elim (value⇒normal v (, e))
deterministic (appʳ f e) (appˡ f′ _) = ⊥-elim (value⇒normal f (, f′))
deterministic (appʳ f e) (appʳ f′ e′) = cong _ (deterministic e e′)

Halts : ∀ {Γ t} → Tm Γ t → Set
Halts e = ∃ λ e′ → e ==>* e′ × Value e′

value⇒halts : ∀ {Γ t e} → Value {Γ} {t} e → Halts e
value⇒halts {e = e} v = e , ε , v

-- -- This would not be strictly positive!
-- data Saturated : ∀ {Γ t} → Tm Γ t → Set where
--   fun : ∀ {t u} {f : Tm [] (fun t u)} → Halts f → (∀ {e} → Saturated e → Saturated (app f e)) → Saturated f

mutual
  Saturated : ∀ {t} → Tm [] t → Set
  Saturated e = Halts e × Saturated′ _ e

  Saturated′ : ∀ t → Tm [] t → Set
  Saturated′ (fun t u) f = ∀ {e} → Saturated e → Saturated (app f e)

saturated⇒halts : ∀ {t e} → Saturated {t} e → Halts e
saturated⇒halts = proj₁

step‿preserves‿halting : ∀ {Γ t} {e e′ : Tm Γ t} → e ==> e′ → Halts e ⇔ Halts e′
step‿preserves‿halting {e = e} {e′ = e′} step = equivalence fwd bwd
  where
    fwd : Halts e → Halts e′
    fwd (e″ , ε , v) = ⊥-elim (value⇒normal v (, step))
    fwd (e″ , s ◅ steps , v) rewrite deterministic step s = e″ , steps , v

    bwd : Halts e′ → Halts e
    bwd (e″ , steps , v) = e″ , step ◅ steps , v

step‿preserves‿saturated : ∀ {t} {e e′ : Tm _ t} → e ==> e′ → Saturated e ⇔ Saturated e′
step‿preserves‿saturated step = equivalence (fwd step) (bwd step)
  where
    fwd : ∀ {t} {e e′ : Tm _ t} → e ==> e′ → Saturated e → Saturated e′
    fwd {fun s t} step (halts , sat) = Equivalence.to (step‿preserves‿halting step) ⟨$⟩ halts , λ e → fwd (appˡ step _) (sat e)

    bwd : ∀ {t} {e e′ : Tm _ t} → e ==> e′ → Saturated e′ → Saturated e
    bwd {fun s t} step (halts , sat) = Equivalence.from (step‿preserves‿halting step) ⟨$⟩ halts , λ e → bwd (appˡ step _) (sat e)

step*‿preserves‿saturated : ∀ {t} {e e′ : Tm _ t} → e ==>* e′ → Saturated e ⇔ Saturated e′
step*‿preserves‿saturated ε = id
step*‿preserves‿saturated (step ◅ steps) = step*‿preserves‿saturated steps ∘ step‿preserves‿saturated step
```

Note that I have removed the `bool` and `pair` types since they are not necessary to show my problem.

The problem, then, is with `msubst_R` (which I call `saturate` below):

```
data Instantiation : ∀ {Γ} → [] ⊢⋆ Γ → Set where
  [] : Instantiation []
  _▷_ : ∀ {Γ t σ} → Instantiation {Γ} σ → ∀ {e} → Value {_} {t} e × Saturated e → Instantiation (σ ▷ e)

saturate-var : ∀ {Γ σ} → Instantiation σ → ∀ {t} (x : Var t Γ) → Saturated (subst-var σ x)
saturate-var (_ ▷ (_ , sat)) vz = sat
saturate-var (env ▷ _) (vs x) = saturate-var env x

app-lam* : ∀ {Γ t} {e e′ : Tm Γ t} → e ==>* e′ → Value e′ → ∀ {u} (f : Tm _ u) → app (lam t f) e ==>* subst (⊢⋆-refl ▷ e′) f
app-lam* steps v f = gmap _ (appʳ (lam _ _)) steps  ◅◅ app-lam f v ◅ ε

saturate : ∀ {Γ σ} → Instantiation σ → ∀ {t} → (e : Tm Γ t) → Saturated (subst σ e)
saturate env (var x) = saturate-var env x
saturate env (lam u f) = value⇒halts (lam u _) , sat-f
  where
    f′ = subst _ f

    sat-f : ∀ {e : Tm _ u} → Saturated e → Saturated (app (lam u f′) e)
    sat-f sat@((e′ , steps , v) , _) =
      Equivalence.from (step*‿preserves‿saturated (app-lam* steps v f′)) ⟨$⟩ saturate ([] ▷ (v , Equivalence.to (step*‿preserves‿saturated steps) ⟨$⟩ sat)) f′
saturate env (app f e) with saturate env f | saturate env e
saturate env (app f e) | _ , sat-f | sat-e = sat-f sat-e
```

`saturate` doesn't pass the termination checker, because in the `lam` case, `sat-f` recurses into `saturate` on `f′`, which isn't necessarily smaller than `lam u f`; and `[] ▷ e′` is also not necessarily smaller than `σ`.

Another way of looking at why `saturate` doesn't terminate is to look at `saturate env (app f e)`. Here, recursing into `f` and (potentially) `e` will grow `t`, even though all the other cases either leave `t` the same and shrink the term, or shrink `t`. So if `saturate env (app f e)` didn't recurse into `saturate env f` and `saturate env e`, the recursion in `saturate env (lam u f)` would not be problematic in itself.

However, I think my code does the right thing for the `app f e` case (since that's the whole point of lugging around the parametric saturation proof for function types), so it should be the `lam u f` case where I need a tricky way in which `f′` is smaller than `lam u f`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an additional `Bool` base type, `Saturated` would look nicer the following way, since it would not demand a `Halts` for the `fun` argument which already follows from `Saturated`.

```
Saturated : ∀ {A} → Tm [] A → Set
Saturated {fun A B} t = Halts t × (∀ {u} → Saturated u → Saturated (app t u))
Saturated {Bool} t = Halts t
```

Then, in `saturate` you can only recurse on `f` in the `lam` case. There is no other way to make it structural. The job is to massage the hypothesis from `f` into the right shape using the reduction/saturation lemmas.

```
open import Function using (case_of_)

saturate : ∀ {Γ σ} → Instantiation σ → ∀ {t} → (e : Tm Γ t) → Saturated (subst σ e)
saturate env (var x) = saturate-var env x
saturate env (lam u f) =
  value⇒halts (lam _ (subst _ f)) ,
  λ {u} usat →
    case (saturated⇒halts usat) of λ {(u' , u==>*u' , u'val) →
      let hyp = saturate (env ▷ (u'val , Equivalence.to (step*‿preserves‿saturated u==>*u') ⟨$⟩ usat)) f
      in {!!}} -- fill this with grunt work
saturate env (app f e) with saturate env f | saturate env e
saturate env (app f e) | _ , sat-f | sat-e = sat-f sat-e
```

Comment: You may also look at [this](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/misc-stuff/blob/master/agda/oplss/WeakEval.agda) for weak call-by-name evaluation in Agda.

Comment: Note that in my real code, I do have the `bool` type from the SF book, I just didn't include it in my code here for brevity.